# Select principal non-null (phone) numbers among several fields in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, algorithm

My current problem deals with phone numbers, and even if it could apply to many other situations, I find it more explicit with phone numbers, so here we go:

I have a Postgresql table with several fields corresponding to phone numbers customer may have provided. Namely, I have `phone_personal`, `phone_professional` `mobile_phone_personal`, `mobile_phone_professional` (these fields are filled from a website I don't have access to).

An external company asks me to retrieve the two principal phone numbers for each customer (I call them phone_1 and phone_2 in the following).

I thought I could work out something with an explicit use of `case` and `coalesce`, in order to:

- at least retrieve a phone number as phone_1  (except all numbers are null of course)
- do not retrieve two identical phone numbers (if only one phone number is provided among the four fields, only retrieve this one as phone_1, and null as phone_2)

```sql
select coalesce(phone_personal, phone_professional, mobile_phone_personal, mobile_phone_professional)
       as phone_1
     , case when coalesce(phone_personal, phone_professional) is null
            then case when mobile_phone_personal is null
                      then null --in that case mobile_phone_professional is taken as phone_1 already
                      else mobile_phone_professional -- as mobile_phone_personal is taken as phone_1 already
                      end
            else case when phone_personal is null -- in that case phone_professional is phone_1
                      then coalesce (mobile_phone_personal, mobile_phone_professional)
                      else coalesce (phone_professional, mobile_phone_personal, mobile_phone_professional)
                      end 
            end 
       as phone_2
```

That looks quite clumsy, and I am quite sure this is inefficient. At best, it is just ugly.

I believe this is a very standard problem, does anybody have an idea to improve this query ?

Comment: Consider how simple this would be with properly *normalised* data; `PhoneNumbers` table with 1 row per number and a column to indicate its priority.

Comment: Well, that might be right. I don't have a write access to the source database though (that does not discard your comment, of course).

Comment: You are correct the query is clumsy and probably inefficient. However, this is a function of very bad design decision.  But, given that design what you have is about a good as it gets. Just shows the complexity you get into with *non normalized* data.

Comment: There's something I'm missing here. How would a table with all phone numbers be more normalized ? Should I have a table for each phone number type ? Or should I have a single ```PhoneNumbers``` table with a column for the phone number and another column to indicate its type (plus another column to indicate the id of the user it refers to, I guess)  ? But in that case, I end up with a Entity-Value-Attribute design, which I thought should be avoided as possible ?

Answer (score 0):

supposing you have:

```
u: postgres db: daf # select * from client;                                                                                                                                                                        
 id | cid |     p1     |     p2     |     p3     |     p4                                                                                                                                                          
----+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------                                                                                                                                                     
  1 |   1 | 1140751234 | [null]     | 1140751203 | [null]                                                                                                                                                          
  2 |   2 | 1140751235 | [null]     | 1140751204 | [null]                                                                                                                                                          
  3 |   3 | [null]     | 1140751235 | 1140751204 | [null]                                                                                                                                                          
  4 |   7 | 1140751206 | [null]     | [null]     | 1140751236                                                                                                                                                      
(4 rows)
```

Try to flip the info:

```
select * from (
select cid, p1 from client where cid = 1 union 
select cid, p2 from client where cid = 1 union 
select cid, p3 from client where cid = 1 union 
select cid, p4 from client where cid = 1 
) as tmp
where p1 is not null
limit 2;
```

Don't forget an index:

```
create index idx_client_cid on client (cid);
```

Based on a table:

```
create table client ( id serial, cid int not null, p1 varchar, p2 varchar, p3 varchar, p4 varchar);
```

Comment: I think I get your point, but that requires to rewrite again the data back to the columnar form afterwards. Moreover, I wish to retrieve the info for all customers. I might work out something with partitions maybe.